# Removing the media="screen" attribute from a stylesheet injected via wp_head()

Tags: wordpress

I have all my CSS in one stylesheet with multiple media queries for handling responsive layout/style changes and print styles.

Print styles aren't getting loaded because the single stylesheet is being written into the head like so with the media attribute set to screen:

`<link rel="stylesheet" id="screen-css" href="pathtomyassets/style.css?ver=3.8.3" type="text/css" media="screen">`

Is there a better way of removing the media attribute or setting its value to 'all' other than using `wp_deregister_style()` and `wp_register_style()`?

Comment: As per the title it is being done through wp_head()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safe way to add/enqueue a CSS style file (and change it's link properties) to the Wordpress generated page is by using the `wp_enqueue_style()` function. If it was first registered with `wp_register_style()` **it can now be added using its handle**.

It is used like this:

`<?php wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); ?>`

The last parameter is interesting in your case, `$media` could be `(string|boolean)` and it is (optional). It is a `string`, specifying the **media for which this stylesheet has been defined**.

Examples: `'all', 'screen', 'handheld', 'print'`.

See [this list](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types) for the full range of valid CSS-media-types. The default value is `'all'`.

Search for this function in your theme's `functions.php` file (or if you use framework/commercial theme search in files like `options.php` or `framework-options.php`) and find how it is invoked and then change the function's last `$media` parameter.